# PostgreSQL 9.3: Adding new Fields to JSON Type

Tags: json, postgresql

Could somebody please explain to me what I have to do if I want to add another Field to a JSON type in PostgreSQL 9.3? It seems that there are many Functions to get the data out of a JSON, but nothing to simply add another field. Or did I overlook something?

If I have for example these relations:

```
Id|     Data (JSON)
1 | {"items": ["abc", "def", "ghi"], "user_id": 328252955}
2 | {"items": ["klm"], "user_id": 328250000}
3 | {"items": ["abc", ghi], "user_id": 328252955}
...
```

What do I have to do if I want to add a field called "name" with the content "foo bar" to the first row?

Thank you for your help. It will be much appreciated!

Comment: Simple answer: you can't - at least not with SQL. You always need to re-write the whole column.

Comment: I was fearing that. Thank you for your anwser.

Comment: 9.4 may add functions to manipulate json (add fields, etc) but it'll still require setting the whole column, it'll just make manipulating the json easier.

Comment: well that diminshes the flexibility of json quite much...

Answer (score 0):

There's always Python...

```
create or replace function jsonset(orig json, attr text, val json)
  returns json language plpythonu as
  $$
  import json
  odict = json.loads(orig)
  odict[attr] = json.loads(val)
  return json.dumps(odict)
  $$;
```

Then you can do:

```
update mytable set 
  Data = jsonset(Data, 'name', '"foo bar"'::json)
  where Id = 1;
```